# Eclipse External Tools configurations

Tags: eclipse

I want to run a program with this arguments

```
-f "${workspace_loc}:/${project_name}/${config_name:${project_name}}/${project_name}.bin}" -r
```

but when I run it I got this error:

```
Variable references empty selection: ${project_name}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `${project_name}` you must have a project selected in a view when you run the tool.

Comment: ok, then I got his message:  Could not open file: C:\TD\TD_RF_Module_SDK-v4.0.0\workspace:/hot_cold/TD1204 Release/hot_cold.bin}.